# raw_input loop bug requires two answers

Tags: python, raw-input

In this section of code when either of the questions is answered it will ask it a second time and only then will it return the result. Say if it asked you Do you pick up the stick? (input Y or N) and you answer Y it would prompt the question a second time. I am looking for a fix for this, any idea? The function in question is choice1

```
    # Project
# Created By: Misha 

import time
import random

weapon = 0

def intro():
    time.sleep(3)
    print "You wake up."
    time.sleep(1)
    print "..."
    time.sleep(1)
    print "You are surrounded by white tiled walls and floors"
    time.sleep(2)
    print "You do not remember anything"
    time.sleep(1)
    print "Ahead of you are two doors."
    time.sleep(2)
    print "One leads to the left and the other to the right"
    print ""

def choose_door1():
  chosen_door1 = ""
  while chosen_door1 != "L" and chosen_door1 != "R":
    time.sleep(2)
    chosen_door1 = raw_input("Which door do you take? (input L or R)")
  return chosen_door1

def proceed_1(chosen_door1):
  if chosen_door1 == "L":
    time.sleep(2)
    print "You head through the left door"
    time.sleep(2)
    print "There is a stick lying on the ground"
    time.sleep(2)
  elif chosen_door1 == "R":
    time.sleep(2)
    print "You head through the right door"
    time.sleep(2)
    print "There is a keypad on the wall"

def choice1(chosen_door1):
  if chosen_door1 == "L":
    choice_left1 = ""
    while choice_left1 != 'Y' and choice_left1 != 'N':
      time.sleep(2)
      print ""
      choice_left1 = raw_input("Do you pick up the stick? (input Y or N)")
    return choice_left1
  elif chosen_door1 == "R":
    choice_right1 = ""
    while choice_right1 != 'Y' and choice_right1 != 'N':
      time.sleep(2)
      print ""
      choice_right1 = raw_input("Do you input anything in the keypad? (input Y or N)")
    return choice_right1

def action_left1(choice_left1):
  if choice_left1 == "Y":
    print "You equipped the Stick!"
    weapon = 1
  elif choice_left1 == "N":
    print "You left the stick lying on the ground"
  else:
    print "ERROR"

def action_right1(choice_right1):
  if choice_right1 == "Y":
    print "You decided to input something into the keypad"
    print ""
  elif choice_right1 == "N":
    print "You decided to not enter anything into the keypad"
    time.sleep(1)
    print "You went back the way you came and went into the left door"


intro()
chosen_door1 = choose_door1()
proceed_1(chosen_door1)
choice1(chosen_door1)
if chosen_door1 == "L":
  action_left1(choice1(chosen_door1))
elif chosen_door1 == "R":
  action_right1(choice1(chosen_door1))
```

Comment: Well, we can't debug your function if we don't know how/in what context it was called.

Comment: this works just fine for me, something must be wrong with the code where you're calling this function.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
 if chosen_door1 == "L":
    action_left1(choice1(chosen_door1))
 elif chosen_door1 == "R":
    action_right1(choice1(chosen_door1))
```

Comment: No, the problem is that the code already asks the question twice. I need it to only be asked once.

Comment: @MishaMatveev well, it's asking only once if you consider only the part of the code you've shared.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove line 82 **choice1(chosen_door1)**

```
intro()
chosen_door1 = choose_door1()
proceed_1(chosen_door1)
choice1(chosen_door1) # REMOVE THIS LINE
if chosen_door1 == "L":
  action_left1(choice1(chosen_door1))
elif chosen_door1 == "R":
  action_right1(choice1(chosen_door1))
```